# Как сделать toggle-button в Blend?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

Работаю в Blend для Visual Studio 2013, понадобилось сделать toggle-button, однако все что я умею - это переключатель в виде кнопки, где в один момент времени виден только один вариант положения переключателя. 
И вот мне понадобилось сделать его немного другим: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я без понятия как это осуществить в Blend, т.к. работал там достаточно мало, а времени курить мануалы нет. Если вас это не затруднит, был бы благодарен за step-by-step руководство, как сделать togglebutton идентичным тому что на картинке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что описано в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818235/218063), делается гораздо проще, без кодбихайнда:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
    <RadioButton Content="On" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Off"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так действительно проще, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Наверно самым простым решением будет использовать 2 кнопки ToggleButton и 1 stack panel.
Алгоритм работы следующий:

1. Создаем горизонтальный StackPanel и ложим в него 2 ToggleButtons. Подписываемся на Checked и Unchecked этих ToggleButtons.
2. В Checked и Unchecked обработчиках принудительно отключаем другой ToggleBotton, т.е. если Checked_ToggleButton1, то делаем Uncheked_ToggleButton2.

Вот Xaml code:

```
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="tgl1" Content="Кнопка 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="tgl2" Content="Кнопка 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Вот C# code:

```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tgl1.Checked += Tgl1_Checked;
        tgl1.Unchecked += Tgl1_Unchecked;
        tgl2.Checked += Tgl2_Checked;
        tgl2.Unchecked += Tgl2_Unchecked;
        tgl1.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void Tgl2_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tgl1.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void Tgl2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tgl1.IsChecked = false;
    }

    private void Tgl1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tgl2.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void Tgl1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tgl2.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

В итоге получаем вот такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я верно понял ваш вопрос, то это решение должно вам помочь.

p.s. Конечно это решение просто в лоб. Если делать по хорошему, то можно создать UserControl, всю логику организовать внутри него, добавить недостающих DependencyProperty, подправить стили элементов, чтобы было как у вас.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы и правда мне помогли.

Comment: @bittip303 Если ответ вас устраивает, то пожалуйста, отметьте его "галкой" с левой стороны от ответа.